# Is it possible to get the .offset() of an an nth-child selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, css-selectors

For some reason I get a null error when I run

```
$('.art:nth-child(2)').offset();
```

while

```
$('.art:first').offset()
```

and

```
$('.art:last').offset()
```

give values, no problem. Will offset() only return values for the first and last children?

HTML:

```
<div class="row_titles">
        <a href="#"><img class="art" src="images/channel_art/netflix-trainspotting.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="art" src="images/channel_art/netflix-ronin.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="art" src="images/channel_art/netflix-camelot.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="art" src="images/channel_art/netflix-the_fighter.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="art" src="images/channel_art/netflix-johnmalkovich.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="art" src="images/channel_art/netflix-memento.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="art" src="images/channel_art/netflix-star_trek.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img class="art" src="images/channel_art/netflix-diehard.jpg" /></a>            
    </div>
```

Comment: Most probably it's the selector's fault, and not the `offset()`. Share your markup so we know if `.art:nth-child(2)` is selecting an element.

Comment: Ok, added the HTML to the post.

Comment: @nipponese [It's definitely the selector's fault](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/hCyVE/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nth-child` selector is selecting the *children* of your `.art` images - and since they don't have any children, this is null.

You could try `.row_titles:nth-child(2)`, or `.art:eq(2)` - either of those should work.

Hope this helps!